# Is there a difference between Avimukteswara and Visvesvara?

Tags: shiva, puranas, shiva-lingam, jyotirlinga, kashi

The original Kashi Vishwanatha temple is thought to have been at the place that the Gyanvapi mosque stands, the original temple having been razed by Aurangzeb. However I came across two articles ([article 1](https://pragyata.com/resolving-the-conundrum-of-visvesvara-jyotirlinga-and-wuzukhana-shivalinga/) and [article 2](https://pragyata.com/the-misconception-about-the-antiquity-and-location-of-the-first-original-site-of-visveswara-jyotirlinga-kashi-vishwanath/)) which are based on the book, ‘Varanasi Vaibhav’, by one Pt. Kubernath Sukul and works of others.

The articles state that two lingas existed in Varanasi, Visvesvara and Avimuktesvara located nearby. With time,  a misconception has come that the Visvesvara Jyotirlinga and Avimuktesvara Linga are the same (अविमुक्तेश्वर एव विश्वेश्वरः।). One takes proofs from some old manuscripts of the Vamana Purana,  Linga Purana and critical edition of Skanda purana to support the contention. They say these are older than the Kashi Khanda of the present Skanda Purana, which mentions Avimukta as the linga which was left behind when Divodasa kicked out the devatas from Kashi.

As per it, the original Vishwanatha temple was at the site where the Bibi Razia mosque in Varanasi stands today. It is right opposite Gate 4 of the Kashi Vishwanatha corridor. The same place where Raja Jai Singh had the Adi Visvesvara temple built as a mark showing this place to be the original Visvesvara temple. It states that there is still a Visvesvara mound indicating one of the prongs of Shiva’s trishula on which Kashi stands during pralaya. The same is at the site of the Bibi Razia mosque.  Due to the mosque, the linga was moved to the site of the Avimukta Linga, the second most important linga of Varanasi. Subsequently, after the attack by Aurangzeb in 1669, the Visvesvara Linga was put in the Gyanvapi to prevent it from damage. The linga which was discovered in the survey in May, 2022 is actually the Avimuktesvara linga.

Basically, Bibi Razia is the site of the original Visvesvara Jyotirlinga and Gyanvapi mosque is the site of the Avimuktesvara Linga.

---

**Questions**

1. I would like to know, based on scriptural reference whether the Avimukta and Visvesvara are two separate Lingas or both names refer to the most important Linga of Shiva at Kashi.
2. If both are separate, which is the most important of two and what are the stories behind their manifestation.
3. Since the article says that Avimukta is older than Visvesvara, which of them is the Jyotirlinga? Shouldn’t it ideally be Avimukta?
4. Also, is the contention of the article, as explained above, about the location (Bibi Razia being Visvesvara and Gyanvapi being Avimuktesvara), correct?